# Create a hyperlink input field from Custom Object which when clicked should redirect to Order Number

Tags: hyperlink, lookup-field

I want to have an input field in a page layout in my Product Object.
That field should store an 8-digit number which will correspond to an order number.
I want to store that value and have a hyperlink to the corresponding Order Number in the Object Order.
Is that possible? Thank You for any kind of help.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE!. Please see [ask] on getting the most from the community. What have you tried so far? Did you look at the HYPERLINK formula function?